# Java outputting arrays and JOptionPane

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jlabel, joptionpane

I was following a tutorial on arrays and wanted to know how I would go about changing this so that the `showMessageDialog` result shows the all the names in the message dialog window instead of one by one (I know it's in a for loop so it will pop up 1 window at a time with each name). I tried doing names[0] + " " + names[1] .. etc. but how would it work if there are more names entered then I expected?

I want the window to display all the names input, I don't know how it will be done without a loop to get each element.

**The code:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    int length;
    String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter amount of friends you have");
    length = Integer.parseInt(input);
    String[] names = new String[length];
    
    for(int counter = 0; counter < names.length; counter++) {
        names[counter] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter friend " + (counter + 1));
    }
   
    for (int counter = 0; counter < names.length; counter++) {  // talking about this
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your friends are: " + names[counter] );
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Hard code data for the names. 2)  *"i was following a tutorial"* What tutorial? Link it. Any tutorial that mixes command line input & GUI presentation is fundamentally broken. Find a better tutorial. 3) I expect (and could confirm if there was an MRE / SSCCE) that both the existing answers will fail, because the default `JLabel` used to display info in a `JOptionPane` ignores newline characters. Instead we might use a `JTextArea` or HTML format in the `JLabel`.

Comment: 4) Alluding back to the 2nd point. I was confused by `Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);`. This scanner is not referenced anywhere else in the code & should be removed.

Comment: Then use a [GUI based tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/). All creation and update of GUI components should be done on the EDT (for starters).

Answer (score 2):

One of several possible solutions:

```
StringBuilder allNames = new StringBuilder();
names.forEach(name -> allNames.append(name).append("\n"));
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your friends are: " + allNames.toString() );
```

Comment: This answer does not use the system specific EOL character and will fail in any case since a `JLabel` (as used as the default display element in a `JOptionPane`) ignores the EOL character in any form.

Answer (score 0):

Another neat solution is with Googles guava library and the Joiner class (but it needs the external dependency Guava instead of pure JRE functions):

```
String allNames = com.google.common.base.Joiner.on('\n').join(names);
```

More on the Joiner class at https://www.baeldung.com/guava-joiner-and-splitter-tutorial

Comment: This answer does not use the system specific EOL character and will fail in any case since a `JLabel` (as used as the default display element in a `JOptionPane`) ignores the EOL character in any form.